# Can we blink a primary tab after opening it via any css or js?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, css, sforce

I am trying to open a primary via this:

```
sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null, '/lightning/n/***', true, 'TestSearch', openSuccess, 'salesforceTab');
```

Now if I pass `false`, the tab opens and does not gets focus, but is there a way to make the unfocused tab blink?

Also can we open more than one primary tab?

**Update**

When we try to move to lightning, we have an api for tab creation, and there is a method which highlights the tab.

```
onTabCreated : function(objComponent, objEvent) {
    let strTabId = objEvent.getParam('tabId');
    let objWorkspaceAPI = objComponent.find("workspace");
    objWorkspaceAPI.setTabHighlighted({
        tabId: strTabId,
        highlighted: true,
        options: {
            pulse: true,
            type: "success"
        }
    });
}
```

Using this I can highlight the tab, but only a red mark comes up on the tab and also the pulse option does not work as it is defined in the documentation? Is this the correct way to use the pulse.?

Comment: That sounds *horrible*.

Comment: By blink I mean the title of it. Not the complete tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this using the setTabHighlighted method and triggering it via setInterval method:

Helper:

```
startShowingText: function (workspaceAPI) {
    workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function (response) {
        var focusedTabId = response.tabId;
        workspaceAPI.setTabHighlighted({
            tabId: focusedTabId,
            highlighted: true,
            options: {
                pulse: true,
                type: "success"
            }
        }).then(function (objPageInfo) {
            workspaceAPI.setTabLabel({
                tabId: objPageInfo.tabId,
                label: 'Test1'
            })
        });
    })
},

stopShowingText: function (workspaceAPI) {
    workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function (response) {
        var focusedTabId = response.tabId;
        workspaceAPI.setTabHighlighted({
            tabId: focusedTabId,
            highlighted: false,
            options: {
                pulse: true,
                type: "success"
            }
        }).then(function (objPageInfo) {
            workspaceAPI.setTabLabel({
                tabId: objPageInfo.tabId,
                label: ' '
            })
        });
    })
}
```

Controller :

```
    var counter = 1;
    setInterval(function() {
        if (counter++ % 2) {
            helper.startShowingText(workspaceAPI);
        } else {
            helper.stopShowingText(workspaceAPI);
        }
    }, 2000);
```